# Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference in Adapter AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, rss

I am trying to make a Fragment which is going to show me the News from RSS channel. I am using a RecyclerView with CardView. My program shows the list of news correct, but when i click on one of this news i recieve this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.myapplication.Model.ItemClickListener.onClick(android.view.View, int, boolean)' on a null object reference
> at com.example.myapplication.Model.FeedViewHolder.onClick(FeedAdapter.java:38)

My code (FeedAdapter.java):

```
package com.example.myapplication.Model;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.myapplication.R;

class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{


    public TextView txtTitle, txtPubDate, txtContent;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public FeedViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        txtPubDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPubDate);
        txtContent = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(v, getBindingAdapterPosition(), false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(v, getBindingAdapterPosition(), true);
        return true;
    }
}

public class FeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedViewHolder>{

    private RSSObject rssObject;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public FeedAdapter(RSSObject rssObject, Context mContext) {
        this.rssObject = rssObject;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FeedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new FeedViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FeedViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtTitle.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtPubDate.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getPubDate());
        holder.txtContent.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getContent());

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink()));
        browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mContext.startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return rssObject.items.size();
    }
}
```

In my dreams, after clicking on a Row object, browser should open the current news page. But i don't know what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You never actually set the listener to the View Holder i.e `setItemClickListener` is never called.

Comment: xD that's true. Thank you! It helps